# openCV - vector calculation

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, normalization

I got a 2-dimensional vector like ...

```
Vec2f u(3, 10);
Vec2f v(4, 5);
```

Using the type `point2f` instead of `Vec2f` normalizing vector would be possible using these lines:

```
cv::Point2f u(3, 10);
double normalizedValue = sqrt(pow(p.x, 2) + pow(p.y, 2));
```

---

- How can I normalize the vector u `(Vec2f)` to get `||u||` as double?
- How can I multiply two vectors `u⋅v` to get a value as double?
- How to calculate the **ninety-degree counterclockwise rotation** of u (`u⊥`) ?

---

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's actually simple: `double normaizedValue = sqrt(pow(u[0], 2) + pow(u[1], 2));`

Comment: For multiplication, take a look on `cv::Vec::cross()` and `cv::Vec::mul()`.

Comment: Then you have to do the multiplication manually.

Comment: I don't know what `cv::Vec::mul()` does, but the dot product is `double dotProduct = u[0]*v[0] + u[1]*v[1];`, (which in this case comes out to 62).